# How do you show FPS and ping in GW2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know for the original *Guild Wars*, there was a switch/option `-perfs` that displays FPS and ping in the upper-right corner. Does *Guild Wars 2* have a similar option?

Comment: There is nothing in the [Official Wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Command_line) for it yet. But there is an example with `-perf` switch. I cannot access the game at the moment to test what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just added `-perfs` to the shortcut and it displays a ton of what looks like graphics related data, including FPS. I didn't see ping though.

I'm not sure what it looked like in Guild Wars, as I never played it.

Comment: You should only need -perf, not -perfs.

Comment: While this worked at the time of posting, `-perf` no longer works since bwe3 which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 11):

You can view your FPS and Ping at the bottom of the first tab of the options window (F11).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows, the Task Manager can be used to get the approximate ping time for gw2 by doing the following steps:

1. Open Task Manager with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>esc</kbd> and goto `Performance` tab.
2. Click on `Resource Monitor` on the lower right.
   [image]
3. Goto the `Network` tab.
4. Find `gw2.exe` and click its checkbox under "Processes with Network Activity".
   [image]
5. The ping time for gw2 is displayed in the "Latency" column under "TCP Connections".

This is the next best thing at least until the game provides a built-in method for showing the ping directly.

Answer (score 1):

A-net have given us a way to look at ping and FPS. There is an overlay app known as Overwolf that lets you check your FPS while on the move. The FPS is shown on a corner of your screen. Hope this helps.